# How to make "code completion" in android studio show suggestions when I write letters in the middle words?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

For example in the image below when I write 's', it shows just suggestions that begin with 's' Without showing suggestions that contains 's' in the middle.

[image]

For example, I want to show "font**s**ize" suggestion, and it really contains 's' in the middle.

I tried to change the "code completion" setting but nothing happened.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the Flutter and dart plugins `Settings -> Plugins` and search for `Dart` from JetBrains and `Flutter` from flutter.dev, it's also recommended to use the latest version of Android Studio.

I am currently using [this version of Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8VDZ.png), with `Flutter` plugin 71.2.2, `Dart` plugin 212.5744, and it [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6M84.png).

Comment: I am currently using the latest version of Android Studio: 
Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390, built on February 17, 2023
and the latest version of Flutter plugin 74.0.1
and the latest version of Dart plugin 221.6103.1
However, the problem is still present